What is the Best Authorization Technique for SSR Pages in Next.js with a Separate Backend
I am building a Next. js app where the first pages are server-side rendered (SSR). The backend for the app is separate and deals with the business logic and data. So I have to add a strong authorization method for these SSR pages security.
I have looked into NextAuth. js works well here based on your specific architecture. In particular, I am worried about:
How well NextAuth. js, which is actually a separate backend.
Whether NextAuth. Another thing is that in this case it might be an overkill to use come up with a polygot state machine with Stately.js for handling SSR authorization.
Alternatives to NextAuth. js for SSR and external backends.
What is the best practice.
